# Verify if there are any selected items in a gridview

Tags: android, gridview

im developing an app and implementing an onboarding to ask the user to select certain options that will be displayed in a grid view. I want the user to select and unselect and item for this im using a simple toggleSelected(){selected=!selected} declared in my item entry class.
I also have a button at the bottom that will be disabled if all the items in the gridview have isSelected() = false. What is the best way to check this?
Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the model class which actually contains the data,the list which you provide to the adapter of the recyclerView , add a variable isSelected and set its default value to false, whenever a grid item gets selected, set it to true and when it gets unselected, set it to false. In this way you could travel that list and then know which all are selected and which are not.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to loop over all the elements and check if any is selected.
But that would be quite resource heavy.

I'd rather suggest that you keep a count of selected elements.
If count != 0, then enable your button.